# Removing specific double quotes from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, quotes

I have a string and I want to get rid of multiple double quotes inside the string as I want to pass it to the field as a string.

For instance:

```
String input = """greeen"" apple juice"
```

It should print.

```
String output = ""greeen" apple juice"
```

Please suggest any easy solution as there are multiple possibilities of having double quotes inside the input string and their individual occurrence I need to preserve.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A String in java  is a sequence of characters enclosed within double quotations. where as in your output how it will be string?

Comment: @ASR I am not concerned with end quotes. They are okay as it needs to be string. The multiple possibilities of 2 or more double quotes inside the string and single entries I need to omit.

Answer (score 1):

Add the + quantifier, which means "one or more":

```
//use    .replaceAll("(\")+", "\"");
input = input.replaceAll("(\")+", "\"");
```

Comment: It's a slight optimisation to use `{2,}` rather than `+` because, in the case of exactly one quote, you'll be doing an unnecessary replacement of `"` for `"`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to use a regex replace to replace more than one quote `"{2,}` with just one `"`.

```
String output = input.replaceAll("\"{2,}", "\"");
```

Comment: No, this does not work. I had tried it before. It still gives me the same string --> """greeen"" apple juice".

Comment: @amar19 Sorry, `replace` is a literal replace. It should have been `replaceAll`, which is a regex replace. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yeah I had also tried with replaceAll, however the output string is --> [ "greeen" apple juice" ], The quotes are not as what I expect. Can you please tell me how can get the double quote at the beginning of the string like this -->  [""greeen" apple juice" ]. The String is processed later so the quotes needs to have both start and end.